# Using DDR4 Optane memory in Asus Pro WRX80E Sage WiFi motherboard

Tags: ubuntu, memory, asus

I am trying to use DDR4 Optane memory in WRX80E SAGE WIFI motherboard with AMD Threadripper 3995WX processor but after connecting it when I turn on the machine it does not boot I tried with a DIMM memory and the machine booted. What would be the problem here? How can I configure DDR4 intel Optane memory to work in the motherboard?

Thanks in advance for the help!.

Answer (score 2):

Intel Optane Persistent Memory is not compatible with AMD CPUs because it uses a proprietary DDR-T protocol that is not implemented on AMD, or any other CPU other than certain Intel Xeon CPU SKUs. [proof - [community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Optane-Persistent-Memory/Is-it-possible-to-utilize-PMem-in-AMD-CPU/m-p/1374849#M298](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Optane-Persistent-Memory/Is-it-possible-to-utilize-PMem-in-AMD-CPU/m-p/1374849#M298) ]